# Enumerate all ELF sections of all shared objects currently loaded

Tags: c, linux, process, dynamic-linking, elf

I am looking for a nice way of enumerating all ELF sections and their addresses of the current binary and all shared objects the current process might have loaded.

I know about the existance of dl_iterate_phdr() which gives me an easy to use list of ELF *segments*, but I am looking for ELF *sections*, so it's not the right call for me.

I don't care about portability, as long as it works on Linux with ELF I am happy!

Any hint appreciated!

Comment: Oh and yes, I am looking for a some C API/code that is suitable for introspecting the process it runs in.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're trying to programmatically access this information from a C/C++ program. I suspect you should be able to do what you want with the [GNU Binary File Descriptor library](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.22/bfd/index.html) (BFD), which is used to implement the GNU linker, objdump, etc. (it also has a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_File_Descriptor_library)). See in particular [section 2.6](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.22/bfd/Sections.html#Sections) of the manual, which is all about sections. BFD creates a linked list of "[struct bfd_section](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.22/bfd/typedef-asection.html#typedef-asection)", accessed through the "sections" member of [struct bfd](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.22/bfd/BFD-front-end.html#BFD-front-end). I think you should be able to open the current binary by using [bfd_fopen](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.22/bfd/Opening-and-Closing.html#Opening-and-Closing) on argv[0]. BFD ships with [binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/).

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a really bad idea, but if you have a legitimate use for it, I would just parse `/proc/self/maps` and open the referenced files. There is no reason to believe that section headers are even mapped into memory; in all likelihood, they're located immediately after `.data` on disk and thus will be overwritten with zeros for `.bss` when the shared object is mapped into memory.

Once you have the files open, you could use `libbfd`, but I would just use `elf.h` directly. It's easy to follow the `Ehdr` to the `Shdr` table.

Answer (score 1):

The readelf command can do this e.g., `readelf -s`

This not trivial, so posting a link to source code for readelf seems like a best choice. One reason for this is the large number of macros required to process header and section structs.

http://rpm5.org/docs/api/readelf_8c-source.html

Comment: That code is vastly complicated by the fact that it's supporting non-native ELF files and thus has to deal with endian and 32/64-bit issues. If you only need to process native ELF files (as in OP's case) the code becomes trivial. Iterating the section headers shouldn't take more than 10-15 lines.

Comment: On my system, the correct command to show sections is `readelf -S [filename]`